# Fallo al reutilizar codigo en javascript en otro archivo

Tags: javascript, html, css

necesito comprimir mi código de manera que sea una función reutilizable, dado que mi experiencia en javascript aun esta muy verde, necesito consejo de gente experta.
Dispongo de este código.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var ladresortTop = $("#unserlandressort").offset().top;
        var landressortBottom = $("#unserlandressort").offset().top + $("#historie").outerHeight();
        var impressionenTop = $("#impressionen").offset().top;
        var impressionenBottom = $("#impressionen").offset().top + $("#impressionen").outerHeight();
        var historieTop = $("#historie").offset().top;
        var historieBottom = $("#historie").offset().top + $("#historie").outerHeight();
        var ortTop = $("#aktivitaeten").offset().top;
        var ortBottom = $("#aktivitaeten").offset().top + $("#historie").outerHeight();
        //var tagebuchTop = $("#tagebuch").offset().top;
        //var tagebuchBottom = $("#tagebuch").offset().top + $("#tagebuch").outerHeight();
        var anreiseTop = $("#anreise").offset().top;
        var anreiseBottom = $("#anreise").offset().top + $("#anreise").outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
        var top_of_screen = $(window).scrollTop();

        if ((bottom_of_screen > ladresortTop) && (top_of_screen < landressortBottom)) {
            $('#one i').css({
                "border-radius": "50px",
                "background": "white",
                "color": "#796029"
            })
        } else {
            $('#one i').css({
                "border": "none",
                "border-radius": "none",
                "background": "none",
                "font-size": "0.8em",
                "color" : "#232653"


            })
        }

        if ((bottom_of_screen > impressionenTop) && (top_of_screen < impressionenBottom)) {
            $('#two i').css({
                "border-radius": "50px",
                "background": "white",
                "color": "#796029"
            })
        } else {
            $('#two i').css({
                "border": "none",
                "border-radius": "none",
                "background": "none",
                "font-size": "0.8em",
                "color" : "#232653"
            })
        }


        if ((bottom_of_screen > historieTop) && (top_of_screen < historieBottom)) {
            $('#three i').css({
                "border": "1px solid white",
                "border-radius": "50px",
                "background": "white",
                "color": "#796029"
            })
        } else {
            $('#three i').css({
                "border": "none",
                "border-radius": "none",
                "background": "none",
                "font-size": "0.8rem",
                "color" : "#232653"

            })
        }



      

        if ((bottom_of_screen > ortTop) && (top_of_screen < ortBottom)) {
            $('#four i').css({
                "border": "1px solid white",
                "border-radius": "50px",
                "background": "white",
                "color" : "#796029"
            })
        } else {
            $('#four i').css({
                "border": "none",
                "border-radius": "none",
                "background": "none",
                "font-size": "0.8rem",
                "color" : "#232653"

            })
        }
        if ((bottom_of_screen > anreiseTop) && (top_of_screen < anreiseBottom)) {
            $('#six i').css({
                "border": "1px solid white",
                "border-radius": "50px",
                "background": "white",
                "color" : "#796029"
            })
        } else {
            $('#six i').css({
                "border": "none",
                "border-radius": "none",
                "background": "none",
                "font-size": "0.8rem",
                "color" : "#232653"

            })
        }

    });
});
```

```css
.events {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.ressortinfo {
    position: relative;
}

.ressortinfo .leftSection {
    background-color: rgba(19, 22, 55, 0.1);
}

.ressortmenu {
    position: sticky;
    top: 10%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
    padding-top: 4em;
}

.ressortmenu ul {
    text-align: right;
    padding: .75rem;
}

.ressortmenu ul > li {
    padding: 15px 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

.ressortmenu ul > li i {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;

}

.ressortmenu ul > li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    top: 30px;
    right: 4px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #232653;
}

.ressortmenu ul > li:last-child:after {
    display: none;
}

.ressortmenu ul > li:focus i, .ressortmenu ul > li:active i {
    color: blue;
}

.ressortmenu span {
    color: #232653;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.css" />

<section class="ressortinfo">
    <div class="columns is-gapless">
        <div class="column is-one-quarter leftSection">
            <?php #progressbar ?>

            <div class="ressortmenu">
                <div class="column is-9 is-offset-3">
                    <?php the_field('menu_text_editor'); ?>
                </div>

                <ul class="is-flex events">
                    <li id="one">
                        <a href="#unserlandressort">
                            <span>Unser Landresort</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="two">
                        <a href="#impressionen">
                            <span>Impressionen</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li id="three">
                        <a href="#historie">
                            <span> Denkmal & Historie</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>

                   

                    <li id="four">
                        <a href="#aktivitaeten">
                            <span>Aktivitäten</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="six">
                        <a href="#anreise">
                            <span>Anreise</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column is-three-quarters">
           <section id="unserlandressort">
                        
                    </section>
        </div>
```

El código en total funciona, pero al trabajar con id especificas, no puedo volver a usarlo en otra pagina, con diferentes id de anclajes, por lo tanto el código no es que sea inútil pero no es bueno ni por asomo y obviamente me gustaría mejorarlo bastante, pero no se como lo puedo hacer "reutilizable" y comprimido. He intentado usarlo tal cual en otro archivo, pero me falla la función completamente y la verdad es que ya no se que mas puedo hacer.
Gracias

**EDITO Y ADJUNTO**

Aqui dejo un enlace a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Saggi/6oqs1vL5/9/#save) con mas contenido, pero por alguna razon la barra de menu no acepta todo e manera correcta

Comment: Siempre y cuando la página en la que quieras utilizar el script, contenga la misma jerarquía, es decir, estructura, no habría ningún problema utilizar la propiedad getElementsByTagName de Javascript en vez del identificador. Un ejemplo puede ser `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]`.

Comment: Las `id`s deben ser únicas en el `DOM` de la página actual. Pero hasta donde tengo entendido, tu puedes usar la misma `id` en diferentes páginas. De ese modo puedes hacer el código que se repite reusable, manteniendo un JS común para todas estas páginas.

Comment: Si necesitas ayuda con el javascript por favor añade el código html no el php. En el javascript utilizas el evento scroll, pero no hay bastante contenido para hacer scroll. Además en el HTML tienes `id` que empiezan con almohadilla : `#unserlandressort` y `id`s repetidos. Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade el código html necesario. Me gustaría ayudar.

Comment: @enxaneta tienes razon, eso fue una metedura de pata.

Comment: El problema es que el contenido es mucho y esta limitado, lo poder en jsFiddle

Answer (score 2):

La forma mas correcta actualmente de reutilizar el codigo es usando separación en modulos. O desde **ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)** puedes utilizar tambien clases. Es la forma mas limpia que yo conozco para reutilizar el codigo.

Mas información sobre clases: [w3c..com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp)

Mas información sobre los modulos: [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import)

Tanto **clases** como **modulos** permiten en los metodos recibir parametros, que pueden ser los identificadores de elementos o los propios elementos. De esta manera el usuario de esta funcion no tiene porque saber como deberian llamarse los elementos, simplemente pasara una lista al metodo, por ejemplo:

```
AplicarScrool('divIzquierdo', 'enlaceMasInformacion', etc.);
```

En general sobre tema de **encapsular**, lo suyo es mirar como esta hecha alguna **libreria**, por ejemplo **JQuery**. Es codigo fuente abierto, puedes ver como lo asignan todo al signo $ y luego tienes acceso a toda la funcionalidad de biblioteca [github jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery).